# Best way to add a class with global variables that doesn't change value in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-variables

Hi everyone I need to create a class that contains variables that will never change. This will be needed in my `Controllers`. So where should I put classes of this type? Should I create a new one or a subfolder in existing ones?

```
namespace MyMVCProject
{
    public class Variables
    {
        public const string actvStat = "Active";
        public const string inctvStat = "Inactive";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one **BaseController** and define required variable as **public constant/read only**, then **inherit** this BaseController **to your Controller**, you can access that variable.

May be no required to add class.

**BaseController**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public const string actvStat = "Active";
    public const string inctvStat = "Inactive";

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class Variables
{
    public const string actvStat = "Active";
    public const string inctvStat = "Inactive";
}
```

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{       
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var classItem1 = Variables.actvStat;
        var item1 = actvStat;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check now i have update answer with both class variable and without class

Comment: Hi @Sandip. Thanks for the idea! But just want to ask why can't I just import my Variables class by using `using`, then call the variable in my `Controller` like this? `if (status == GlobalVariables.inctvStat)`

Comment: For that you have to define your class as static