# How do I initialize needed global variables in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, webforms

In [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx) article there is an explanation of the way of creating SharePoint 2013 add-in in web forms, I need MVC though.

They initialize accessToken, currentUser, and other variables in the Default.aspx.cs file:

In the Default.aspx.cs file of your web application, add these variables inside the Page class.

```
SharePointContextToken contextToken;
string accessToken;
Uri sharepointUrl;
string siteName;
string currentUser;
List<string> listOfUsers = new List<string>();
List<string> listOfLists = new List<string>();
```

Does it really matter where I initialize it in MVC and if it does, where do I have to initialize these? Is HomeController okay?

Sorry for the question's being probably dumb as I am new to both SharePoint and ASP.NET MVC.

P.S.: The question is indirectly connected with SharePoint so I asked it there and not at [SharePoint StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one **BaseController** and define required variable as **public constant/read only**, then **inherit** this BaseController **to your Controller**, you can access that variable.

[Please look at here for more details:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39360937/6606630)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare global variables in app_code folder of your solution,and use it where ever you need.

In App-code you need to add a class file like Global.cs(you can give any name)
and there you can declare global variables.